# Difficulty connecting to RDS via Bastion ec2 instance using RDS endpoint

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have been encountering difficulties when trying to setup an SSH tunnel to connect to a private RDS Aurora cluster via a bastion ec2 instance.

It works fine when I use the private IP that the RDS endpoint resolves to in both my python scripts and in pgadmin.
BUT if I change from the private IP, to the actual RDS endpoint (..us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com), neither my scripts nor pgadmin connect. They give timeout errors.

For reference:
db_ip = the ip or endpoint to RDS, bastion_endpoint = the endpoint for the ec2 instance, bastion_user = ec2-user, key_path = path to identity key file

```
with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
                (bastion_endpoint, 22),
                ssh_username=bastion_user,
                ssh_private_key=key_path, 
                remote_bind_address=(db_ip, 5432),
                local_bind_address=('', 5433)) as server:
```

Curiously when I directly open an SSH tunnel in powershell using:

```
ssh -i <identity key> -f -N -L 5433:<rds ip>:5432 ec2-user@<ec2 endpoint> -v
```

And then run psql:

```
psql -hlocalhost -U<user> -p5433 -d <database>
```

Psql connects quickly.

However, if I change to the endpoint:

```
ssh -i <identity key> -f -N -L 5433:<rds endpoint>:5432 ec2-user@<ec2 endpoint -v
psql -hlocalhost -U<user> -p5433 -d <database>
```

Psql connects... eventually. It takes a few minutes before asking for the password, and then another few minutes before giving me the prompt.

Could I have configured something incorrectly? As best I can tell everything is setup fine. Like it works fine w/ the IP, just not with the endpoint.